# When token is refreshed subsequent API calls pass stale token

Tags: javascript, jwt, axios

I am building a SPA in Vue, and using axios interceptors to handle token management. Now, the SPA is not refreshing the token manually, it is receiving the token from the server only when it is refreshed, and then I update localStorage with the new token. I am passing the token in the headers on every API call.

My problem is that when the token comes back after it's been refreshed, I update localStorage in the response interceptor. But subsequent API calls are not aware of this new value in the store.

How can I retry the requests with the new value in localStorage?

I have tried, in the error block of the response interceptor, to grab the value from localStorage and manually update the headers and return the original request but this doesn't seem to work, as the subsequent API calls fail still with the old value.

```
axios.interceptors.request.use(config => {
  const accessToken = window.localStorage.getItem('authToken')

  if (accessToken) {
    config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${accessToken}`
  }

  return Promise.resolve(config)
})

axios.interceptors.response.use(
  response => {
    if (response.data.meta && response.data.meta.tokens && response.data.meta.tokens.Bearer) {
      const token = response.data.meta.tokens.Bearer
      console.log({ 'setting new token': token })
      window.localStorage.setItem('authToken', token)
    }
    return response
  },
  error => {
    console.log(error)
    const originalRequest = error.config
    if (error.status && error.status === 401 && !originalRequest._retry) {
      originalRequest._retry = true
      const accessToken = window.localStorage.getItem('authToken')
      originalRequest.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${accessToken}`
      return axios(originalRequest)
    }
    return Promise.reject(error)
  }
)
```